# What is the style of mapping used by Google Traffic?

Tags: cartography, style, line, google, traffic

I'm doing a piece of work that involves mapping traffic flow, and will be displaying it in a way that Google Traffic does. I know how to make the maps using QGIS, but is there a specific name for this type of mapping? I need some literature to refer to (i.e. similar papers that use this type of mapping), but don't know what it's called.

[image]

Comment: temporal thematic mapping is a generic term https://books.google.ca/books?id=vIy7eEqEqKkC&lpg=PA29&ots=iCnQ2omKU-&dq=temporal%20thematic%20mapping&lr&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q&f=false